# Meissner Effect for Para/Ferromagnetic substances

Tags: superconductivity

I read that Diamagnetism is a fundamental property of all materials, but it is relatively weaker, and is overridden by the stronger properties like Ferromagnetism. So is it possible, in theory, to make superconductors out of all materials, at a sufficiently low temperature?

Comment: Superconductivity is, as I believe, a property of only a select few materials. Not all materials exhibit this property.

Comment: As for the theory, I know nothing.

Answer (score 0):

A quick answer: superconductivity is still an active field of research, but it has already been found in a lot of different materials. For instance, it has been found in the low temperature sector (and sometimes in the low-temperature and high-pressure sector) of materials which are usually classified at higher temperature as normal metal or insulator, from different structural properties, like ceramic, super-lattice or simple lattice, ... see e.g. this Wikipedia entry on [a possible classification of superconductors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superconductor_classification)

Strictly answering this question, it exists some superconductivity in systems which are ferromagnetic at high temperature, see e.g. the entry on Wikipedia about [Ferromagnetic superconductors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferromagnetic_superconductor) and references therein.

As much of the superconductivity outside the BCS-regime (say roughly the superconductivity of metallic materials having simple lattice structure) the microscopic mechanisms are not well understood.

Obviously, ferromagnetism and superconductivity are antagonist, since one favours correlation of spin in space, whereas the Cooper mechanism favours the pairing of opposite spins. It exists a strong believe that *anti*-ferromagnetism may play a big role for high-temperature superconductors, since the superconducting and antiferromagnetic pockets of the (critical-temperature versus doping)-phase diagram are close to each other.

To conclude, further reading about:

- [Iron-based superconductors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron-based_superconductor)
- [Covalent superconductors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covalent_superconductor)
- [A list of superconductors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_superconductors), absolutely incomplete though